# Нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Все(,) как на подбор" — нужна тут запятая или нет?

Comment: Мало контекста. Могут быть варианты.

Answer (score 4):

В устойчивых сочетаниях запятая перед как не ставится:  все как на подбор, бродить как неприкаянный, бросился как безумный, бубнит как пономарь, вбежал как сумасшедший, вертится как белка в колесе, визжит как поросенок, вижу как днем и т.д.